# Limit of a sequence of measurable functions is measurable: alternative proof

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $f_n$ is an infinite sequence of measurable functions, let $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$.  Prove that $f$ is measurable.

The proof (as I was taught it) is as follows.  If $f(x) > a$, then for some $m \in \mathbb N, f(x) > a + \frac{1}{m}$.  There is an $N$ such that for $n>N$, $f_n(X) > a + \frac{1}{m}$.  Therefore, we have:

$\{x: f(x) > a\} \subset \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty} \bigcup\limits_{N=1}^{\infty} \bigcap\limits_{n=N}^{\infty} \{x: f_n(x) > a + \frac{1}{m}\}$.
The other direction is then proved by considering an $x$ in the set on the right, and demonstrating that for some $N$ and some $m$, $f_n(x) > a + \frac{1}{m}$ for all $n \geq N$, and hence, the limit $f(x) \geq a + \frac{1}{m} > a$.   Hence, the sets above are equal, and $\{x: f(x) > a\}$ is measurable, so $f$ is measurable.

---

Why do we have to introduce this $m$ at all?  What is wrong with the following?

$\{x: f(x) > a\} \subset \bigcup\limits_{N=0}^{\infty} \bigcap\limits_{n=N}^{\infty} \{x: f_n(x) > a \}$.

And then proving the other direction in a similar manner to above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x$ belongs to your RHS. This is equivalent to saying there exists $N$ such that $f_n(x)>a$ for all $n\geq N$. Assume that $f_n(x_0) > f(x_0)$ for all $n$, and put $a = f(x_0)$. Then $x_0$ belongs to your RHS, but not your LHS.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So, without the $\frac{1}{m}$, the LHS is indeed a subset of the RHS, but not the other direction.  Essentially, the $\frac{1}{m}$ is decreasing the size of the RHS by an infinitesimal amount so that it can be a subset of the LHS.